# Someone is installing apps in my android

Tags: uninstallation, malware

I have a Xiomi Redmi HM1SW   with android 4.3 and MIUI.

I notice one month ago that some process is installing apps in my desktop that I don't selected.

How can I disable this option? or kill this malware app?

Thanks,

Comment: what apps have been installed? And what apps have you installed on your device? We need more information...

Comment: That's most likely some app you've installed from "another source", which brought a Trojan along (could also have made it to Playstore – but "other sources" are more likely). So anything you've installed shortly before these auto-installs started? Also, some names of what gets auto-installed might give a clue.

Comment: Might be a family member installing apps [on a computer](http://play.google.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install security 360 from Google play, it should find all malware, and help you remove it.

Comment: "*it will find all malware*" -- **a very bold claim**! How do you know it will find all the malware? Please back your claim with credible technical sources. Also, given the current length and breadth, this rather seems to be a comment than an answer (IMO).

Comment: thanks, taht app cleaned three malware in my android. I hope it is fixed now

Answer (score -1):

It is likely to be a market. Check the use of data because the app must be leeching data to download apps. If it has a huge amount of data and is an android market, uninstall it.

Comment: I don't think an app has the ability to install another app, however I could be wrong.